# Why won't this change the fill amount when i hold light click?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up hold down pick up animation. This code should change the fill amount of the sprite when a left click is pressed but it doesn't. Basically when the player looks an interactable object a pop up shows that tell them to hold the letter E. When they do a progress bar fill up around the letter E. However when i try to use code to change the fill amount of the progress bar. It just doesn't do anything. Ive left some other solutions as comment in the code to show that ive tried everything i know. I am fairly new to unity myself and this is really my first go with it to be honesnt.

I have tried reaching

```cs
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;




public class Interaction : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private new Camera camera; 
    [SerializeField]
    private float pickupTime = 10f; 
    [SerializeField]
    private Image pickProgressImage;
    [SerializeField]
    private RectTransform pickupImageRoot;
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask layerMask; 
    [SerializeField]
    private TextMeshProUGUI itemNameText; 
    private Item itemBeingPickedUp; 
    //private float currentPickupTimerElasped;

    private float TimeTest;



    private void Update()
    {
        SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay();
        if  (HasItemTargetted())
        {
            pickupImageRoot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                //TimeTest += (float)0.1; 
                pickProgressImage.fillAmount += TimeTest;
                //IncrementPickupProgressandTryComplete();

            }
            else;
            {
                //currentPickupTimerElasped = 0f;
                TimeTest = 0f;
            }
             UpdatePickupProgressImage();
        }
        else
        {
            pickupImageRoot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            //currentPickupTimerElasped = 0f;
            TimeTest = 0f;
        }



    }
    private bool HasItemTargetted()
    {
        return itemBeingPickedUp != null;
    }
    private void IncrementPickupProgressandTryComplete()
    {
        TimeTest += (float)0.1; 
        //currentPickupTimerElasped = currentPickupTimerElasped + Time.deltaTime;
       //if (currentPickupTimerElasped >= pickupTime)
       // {
       //     itemBeingPickedUp = null;
            //Start MiniGame
      //  }

    }

    private void UpdatePickupProgressImage()
    {
        //float pct = currentPickupTimerElasped / pickupTime;
        //ProgressBox.fillAmount += pct;
        pickProgressImage.fillAmount += TimeTest;

    }
    private void SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay()
    {
        Ray ray = camera.ViewportPointToRay(Vector3.one / 8f);

        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * 8f, Color.red); 

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 8f, layerMask))
        {
            var hitItem = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Item>();

            if (hitItem == null)

            {
                itemBeingPickedUp = null;
            }
            else if (hitItem != null && hitItem != itemBeingPickedUp)
            {
                itemBeingPickedUp = hitItem; 
                itemNameText.text = "Pickup" + itemBeingPickedUp.gameObject.name;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            itemBeingPickedUp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It should change fill amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Input.GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) is `true` only in exactly **one single** frame - the frame the button goes down.

> Returns `true` during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.

It is `false` in the frames after that!

---

What you probably rather want to use is [`Input.GetMouseButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html)

> Returns whether the given mouse button is held down.

```c#
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
```

which is `true` as long as the button **stays pressed**!

---

However, I don't really understand your usage of `TimeTest` and other variables and methods  here. It might simply be `0`? You imcrement `pickProgressImage.fillAmount` in two different places and also `TimeTest` .. that's a bit confusing for me. And some of your methods are quite redundant.

You don't need further variables for checking if the required time passed... simply check on the `pickProgressImage.fillAmount` itself using [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) for comparing `float` values.

Also for the incrememt you shouldn't use a fixed value of `0.1f` (that's how you declare float values btw) but rather use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) in order to convert an otherwise **framerate-dependent** incrementation to a framerate-independend "imcrement per second" value.

You also don't need method for checking if `itemBeingPickedUp` is set or `null`: Since your `Item` is a `MonoBehaviour` which inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` you can use it's [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) for checking it's existence.

```c#
// How long shall filling from 0 to 1 take in seconds?
// Adjust in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private float pickupTime = 1;

private void Update()
{
    SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay();

    // You don't need a method for this
    // all types inherited from UnityEngine.Object 
    // Have a bool operator which equals a != null
    if (itemBeingPickedUp)
    {
        pickupImageRoot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        // initially reset the fill
        pickProgressImage.fillAmount = 0
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // Use Time.deltaTime in order to convert the otherwise
            // FRAME WISE increment to rather an increment per seconds
            pickProgressImage.fillAmount += Time.deltaTime * pickupTime;

            // You don't need additional methods or variables
            // for checking if enough time passed
            // simply use the fill itself as check
            if(Mathf.Approximately(pickProgressImage.fillAmount, 1))
            {
                // FULLY FILLED -> DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
        else;
        {
            // Reset the fill itself not only your other variables
            pickProgressImage.fillAmount = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pickupImageRoot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        // Reset the fill itself not only your other variables
        pickProgressImage.fillAmount = 0;
    }
}
```

---

As a matter of taste I would actually also make the return type of `SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay` not `void` but rather directly `Item`. This way you don't even need a field for this in your class and you can not forget that it has to be called first or which field it sets:

```c#
private Item SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay()
{
    Ray ray = camera.ViewportPointToRay(Vector3.one / 8f);

    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * 8f, Color.red); 

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitInfo, 8f, layerMask))
    {
        var hitItem = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Item>();

        // your Update already makes a null check so let it handle the outcome
        return hitItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then use it like

```c#
private void Update()
{
    var currentItem = SelectItemBeingInteractedWithFromRay();

    if(currentItem)
    {
        itemNameText.text = "Pickup" + currentItem.name;

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```